# OneToMany wihout specifying of owner's class

Tags: java, sql, database, hibernate, orm

How I could join product with image as oneToMany
wihout specifying of owner's class?
To use 'image' for different owners' tables?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
public class Product extends BaseModel {//baseModel has 'id' column
@Column
private List<Image> images;
}
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "image")
public class Image extends BaseModel {//baseModel has 'id' column
@Column 
private Object owner;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JPA works this way normally.

Your entity Product should be decorated like this:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="imageId")
private List<Image> images;
```

For any other table, you just specify mappedBy column to a proper name

Your entity Image should be decorated like this:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="imageId", nullable=false)
private Product product
```

If you want to reuse some entity, i thing that it is not possible. Best think ever is to not actually use @xTox relations, they just bring pain